# Invoke Java code from C++ crashes on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-ndk-r5, android-ndk-r7

PS: Actually, this is working, I have another problem that I'll update this question soon.

I has the following native code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_rmsdk_wrapper_RMServices_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiso,
        jstring prodName, jstring version) {

    jclass thisClass = env->GetObjectClass(thiso);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "APP", "[findMethodId]");        
    jmethodID getDeviceName = env->GetMethodID(thisClass, "getDeviceName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "APP", "[invoke]");      
    jstring dvcName = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(thiso, getDeviceName);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "APP", "[strings retrivied]");
```

And the respective method at a Java class

```
public String getDeviceName() {
    String deviceName = Build.MODEL;
    LogU.v("APPServices", "getDeviceName("+deviceName+")");
    return deviceName;
}
```

But when running the following happens:

```
D/RMSDK:DRM(3717): [findMethodId]
D/RMSDK:DRM(3717): [invoke]
I/DEBUG(27674): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG(27674): Build fingerprint: 'MOTO/PORTLA/wifi_hubble:3.2/H.6.6-27/1317781165:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys'
I/DEBUG(27674): pid: 3717, tid: 3717  >>> br.com.abril.iba <<<
I/DEBUG(27674): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG(27674):  r0 00000000  r1 40c33038  r2 5651b1ec  r3 be86444c
I/DEBUG(27674):  r4 0000008c  r5 8282a018  r6 82805e28  r7 826f0a68
```

The method are being found, but they crash when invoking it (any method does), how can I fix that? I'm not sure why it's not working.

PS: Same error happens with Android NDK5 & NDK7B

Comment: Are you sure thiso is not NULL? And thisClass is not NULL? And getDeviceName is not NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine on my HTC Desire Z, I compiled the native part using android-ndk-r7b. Are you sure you have method `getDeviceName()` in the same class where you execute `init(String s1, String s2);`?
I used the following java code:

```
public class HelloJni extends Activity {

public native void init(String s1, String s2);



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    init("","");
}

static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}

public String getDeviceName() {
    String deviceName = Build.MODEL;
    Log.v("APPServices", "getDeviceName("+deviceName+")");
    return deviceName;
}
}
```